# how can I compare "hello:"=="hello" in python

Tags: python, selenium

i want to ignore symbols in the string and compare with the non-Symbolic string
`name="Avengers Endgame"`

```js
find_element_by_link_text(name.title()).click()
```

```html
<a href="#">Avengers: Endgame</a>
```

Comment: just put a ":' in your string, you are writing it manually anyway.

Comment: if you have bulk of data then?

Comment: Is it the same issue mentioned in [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57640024/find-element-by-link-text-ignore-symbols-in-string-in-python)?

Comment: yes supputri... i am really thankful to you.... thanks for hel...

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) on the word class (`\W`). From the link,

> ```
> \W
>     Matches any character which is not a word character. This is the opposite of \w. 
>     If the ASCII flag is used this becomes the equivalent of [^a-zA-Z0-9_]. 
>     If the LOCALE flag is used, matches characters considered alphanumeric in 
>     the current locale and the underscore.
> ```

Like,

```
import re
a = 'Avengers Endgame'
b = 'Avengers: Endgame'
if re.sub(r'[\W]', '', a) == re.sub(r'[\W]', '', b):
    print("They match")
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this function for another project. Use re module, I guess it can help you.

```
def convert_string(str):
    '''
    return the string without any signs

    ex :
    input = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456789!@#$%^&*()-=_+'
    ouput = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456789'
    '''

    pat = re.compile(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9]', flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    return pat.sub('', str)
```

Comment: this also strips the whitespace characters which is not what the OP wanted

Answer (score 0):

you could use a generator expression to only yield characters from your string that are alphanumeric or whitespace, then join them back into a new string:

```
text = 'Avengers: Endgame'
stripped_text = ''.join(char for char in text if char.isalnum() or char.isspace())
```

your new string would then be: `Avengers Endgame`