# find element by link text (ignore symbols in string) in python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I am trying to match the string on the web with the string i am passing.
String on the web is contain symbols like - , : ; and i am passing string without symbols

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
name="Ant Man and the Wasp"
driver=webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.movieshunters.com")
search=driver.find_element_by_id('s')
search.clear()
search.send_keys(name)
driver.find_element_by_class_name('search-button').submit()
driver.find_element_by_link_text(name.title()).click()
<a href="https://www.movieshunters.com/movies/ant-man-and-the-wasp/">Ant-Man and the Wasp</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using the xpath. <kbd>translate</kbd> is the method that you have to use.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[translate(.,'-',' ') = 'Ant Man and the Wasp']").get_attribute('href')
```

In your code

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[translate(.,'-',' ') = name]").get_attribute('href')
```

Read more about [translate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/translate) method.

If you want to handle `:-;` in any order then use the below xpath.

```
//a[translate(.,'-;:','   ')='Ant Man and the Wasp']
```

**Screenshot:**
[image]